# System.IO.Pipelines: Receiving continuous messages

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to the concept of **Pipes** and I like to implement a client which receives messages from a server. The server pushes these messages automatically using a fairly constant delay of X seconds. I do understand the basics of Pipes and their usage-scenarios - also, there is a great tutorial on the [MS Dev-Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-io-pipelines-high-performance-io-in-net/). The following question directly refers to this tutorial: I am pretty sure I can use one pipe and the two tasks for **handling all messages** sent from the server until the connection closes, but there are two `break` statements within the loop in the tutorial, where the second statement confuses me regarding my assumption to handle all messages using the two tasks - I understand the first condition

```
int bytesRead = await socket.ReceiveAsync(memory, SocketFlags.None);
if (bytesRead == 0) { break; }
```

but the second one completely confuses me:

```
FlushResult result = await writer.FlushAsync();
if (result.IsCompleted) { break; }
```

What exactly happens here? In which scenarios is `result.IsCompleted` true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipelines.flushresult?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) states:
`IsCompleted` gets a value that indicates the reader is no longer reading data written to the `PipeWriter`.

So this should be a test if the flush and `PipeReader.ReadAsync` succeed.

Like it's described in your linked blog post:

> When the call to PipeReader.ReadAsync() returns, we get a ReadResult which contains 2 important pieces of information, the data that was read in the form of ReadOnlySequence and a bool IsCompleted that lets the reader know if the writer is done writing (EOF).

just the other way around for the `PipeWriter` instead of the `PipeReader`. This seems to be needed since they run in parallel.